# How to backup my rom without pc?

Tags: backup

I have a symphony v50 mobile. I can not go to recovery mod when my phone was switched off. When I go to make a backup of my current rom with rom manager i did not get the backup option. May I change the cwm recovery? If the ans is yes please tell me how. Else how I can make a backup of my current rom?

Comment: I was trying to go recovery mood by hold click volume up+power  buttons.  but not go to recovery. it goes to phone test function

Comment: Additional information pertinent to the question should be edited into the question. Comments are not guaranteed to persist, so the additive information can be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install TWRP recovery and full (or partial) backup can be done to additional SD card plugged to Your phone.